# Dynamic iframe width not working in FF8/IE9

Tags: jquery

I've been trolling Google for the past 4 days with no solutions. I know this has been discussed before, but I'm having some difficulty here.

I am trying to resize an iframe's width on a parent page based on the content (same domain) within the child page. I wrote a little piece of code that works great in IE7/8. It also works in FireBug in FF8; however, it does not work in FF8 or IE9. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<iframe src="child.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var getWidth = $("iframe").contents().width();
$("iframe").css("width", getWidth + "px");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.width()` also takes a parameter:

```
var getWidth = $("iframe").contents().width();
$("iframe").width(getWidth);
```

Comment: Inspecting the HTML in FireBug (FF8), it keeps setting the incorrect css width. When I run the script in the FireBug console, it works correctly returning a width of the child page, but when I view the page in the browser, it consistently sets an incorrect width of 300px -- regardless of the child page's content dimensions. IE 7/8 has no problems.

Comment: How are you running this code? Do you wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: I think I found the answer. Apparently latest versions of FF and IE needs the code below wrapped around the above code.

    $("iframe").load( function() {
    });

Comment: Yep, I was thinking that might do it. The iframe wasn't ready. Post that as an answer and accept it, as it'll at least show that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Everyone does, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apparently, the latest versions of FF and IE need the code below wrapped around the code in my initial question.

```
$("iframe").load( function() {

});
```